# How to change parameters of certain algorithms in QGIS process modeler during run time?

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I am using Process modeler to automate a bunch of things like Create Graticule -> Extract points at the graticule centeroids -> Add coordinates to the points -> update certain fields of the point file with respect to a polygon.

Edit:

The model has run successfully. Except, i would like to change certain parameters during run time with respect to the input file. My question is, is it possible to change the parameters during run time itself ? What i am looking for is, the model should ask for user's input during run time and it should not process the predefined values.

For example, i've five algorithms (A,B,C,D,E) in model. Once the process starts all the algorithms are being processed with predefined parameters (like grid cell size, etc..) and the "E" is giving the final output file. Instead, what i would like to do is, after algorithms A->B the user has to input parameters for "c". It should not be a continuous process. There should be an option for user inputs at certain junctions.

Any ideas please ?

Comment: It's unclear to me what exactly you need. You start the process by providing input. Then the model runs until it finishes. At which point would you again like to provide input and why?

Comment: @underdark I've edited the question. Kindly have a look

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's the idea of a model ... You could just have two models and you start the second one after A->B has finished and input your new parameters. Alternatively, you can write a python script which starts the first model, then asks for input, then starts the second model.